# How to prevent a Port from being used while a service restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 servers. 
Each server hosts multiple services.

Sometimes, when a service is restarted, it fails to bind to the port and says that the port is already in used. Indeed, some system service (or some other service which downloads tons of stuff from multiple websites) might be using the port at that particular moment.

So I retry again and again to bind to the port until it finally succeeds, but this can take some time.

How can I prevent that from happening ? How can I make sure a port is not in used while my service is not running ?

Thanks

Comment: Do your services bind to random ports? Or how come listener port becomes busy? My gutfeeling says it's your process that's just too slow to die and systemd script isn't configured well enough to wait for it to gracefully die.

Comment: I agree with @favoretti. Try to check what is it that is making the port busy, use `sudo netstat -latnp` and you should know which process is holding that port

Answer (score 0):

**option 1** : tune /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range to make sure the port you want your app to listen to is outside the range

**option 2** : use 1 ip per service you are hosting, and ensure that your application actually binds its ip. this one is ok if you don't have a lot of services concerned.